# How can I programmatically bring up the document properties window in Word and go to the Summary tab?

Tags: vba, ms-word, office-addins, word-automation

I am developing a VB6 COM add-in for Microsoft Word and I have added a button to the Ribbon which will save the document to a database.  But before the document is saved, I want to take the user to the document properties window so they can fill in the properties for the document (like *Title*, *Subject* and *Author*).  I am using the following statement to bring up the window:

```
Application.Dialogs(750).Display
```

This works fine, but it defaults to showing them the General tab.  The fields for *Title*, *Subject* and *Author*) are on the Summary tab.  Is there any way to bring up this dialog box and force it over to the *Summary* tab?  I thought about sending keystrokes, but the tabs don't have hotkeys associated with them.

I need this to work in Word 2007 and Word 2010.  The line above already works fine in Word 2003 because 2003 doesn't have a multi-tabbed properties window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bring up a seperate box for this (works in both Word 2000, 2003, 2007 and 2010):

```
Application.Dialogs(wdDialogFileSummaryInfo).Display
```

or

```
Application.Dialogs(86).Display
```

You can also program against this dialog. See [here](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/MacrosVBA/SetDefFilename.htm) for an example.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried using wdDialogFileSummaryInfo with the Display method yesterday but I found that it didn't save anything that was entered into the dialog.  It turns out that you need to use the Show method instead.  Once I tried that, it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You could record a macro then execute it as needed.

Comment: Thanks, but nothing gets recorded in the macro when you bring up the document properties dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Changing .Display to .Show works, except you get an error if you press ESC, so you have to wrap it in On Error Resume Next (no idea why).

```
Sub CustomProperties()
    On Error Resume Next
        Application.Dialogs(750).Show
End Sub
```